# Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} \big[ f(x)+g(x)\big] = p+q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: B \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be functions such that $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$, $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and let $\beta$ be a fixed number. Furthermore let $f(x) = (f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots , f_m(x))$ for each $x \in A$.

Prove the following:

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=p$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}p(x)=q$, then:

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \big[ f(x)+g(x)\big] = p+q$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \beta f(x) = \beta p$

**My attempt for the first bullet:**

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. We must show there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\big| \big| (f(x) + g(x)) - (p+q) \big| \big|_m < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < \big| \big| x - a \big| \big|_p < \delta$

We know, since $f$ and $g$ converge to $p$ and $q$ respectively, there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 >0$ such that

$|| f(x) - p||_m < \epsilon_1$ whenever $0 < ||x-a||_p< \delta_1$

$||g(x) - q||_m < \epsilon_2$ whenever $0 < || x-a ||_p < \delta_2$

Now let $\epsilon = \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ and choose $\delta = \delta_1 + \delta_2$ then

$||f(x) - p||_m + ||g(x) - q||_m < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < ||x-a||_p < \delta$

$\implies || (f(x)-p) + (g(x) -q)||_m \leq ||f(x) -p||_m + ||g(x) - q||_m < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < ||x-a||_p < \delta$

$\implies ||(f(x) + g(x)) - (p+q)||_m < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < ||x-a||_p < \delta$

Thus proving that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \big[ f(x)+g(x)\big] = p+q$

Is this correct? I have a feeling that I am choosing my $\delta$ incorrectly?

Comment: Your definition of limit is wrong. It shouldn't be if and only if!

Comment: @mt_ - Thank you! :). I actually have it as whenever in my book, but for some reason used iff here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are choosing $\delta$ incorrectly. In general, $\|x-a\|_p<\delta_1+\delta_2$ will not make all the inequalities with the epsilons hold, which is what you want.

Instead, take the smallest delta of the two: $\delta =\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. This way both $\|f(x)-p\|_m < \epsilon_1$, and $\|g(x)-q\|_m<\epsilon_2$, so that $$\|f(x)+g(x)-(p+q)\|_m \leq \|f(x)-p\|_m + \|g(x)-q\|_m < \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$$
For the second bullet, just use that $$\|\beta v\| = |\beta|\|v\|$$
for any scalar $\beta$, and vector $v$.

Comment: Thank you! :) . Can you please explain why we have to use the minimum $\delta$ ? :) :). I just want to make sure I so I understand everything about the proof ...

Comment: @Dillon So that $\|x-c\|$ is smaller than both $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ at once.